# Add google nearby to react native library with ios native modules

Tags: swift, react-native, react-library

I'm adding the https://github.com/google/nearby/ to ios modules in my react native library. When compiling the example I'm getting the error

`No such module 'NearbyConnections`

I'm adding the NearybyConnections in the Add Packages option.
I created the react-native library using the `create-react-native-library` and I've selected the option to develop a Native Module and in the languages option I've selected Kotlin and Swift.

I tried to add the lib in the example/ios folder as well and didn't work.

Any tip to recognise it?

Comment: Did you launch `pod install` inside `example/ios`?

Comment: yes I Did, and did not work. It doesn't import the nearbyPackage